# Cabal library vs cabal-install. what's the difference?

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-install

When I do `cabal --version` I see:

```
cabal-install version 0.14.0
using version 1.14.0 of the Cabal library
```

so what's the difference? i thought that when i do `cabal build` i use only one program. why is it split into two separate programs with different versions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Cabal` library defines how package descriptions are parsed and structured, and describe part of the process of building and installing a package. The `cabal-install` package defines the `cabal` *application*. It uses the library to effectively understand what a package description is.

This is a common structure for software: implement all your pure and reusable business logic in a library (the `Cabal` library does most, but not all, of the work purely related to package descriptions), and implement all your user interface stuff and other 'details' in an application that uses the library (the `cabal-install` package defines the CLI tool, and implements the details of fetching packages from Hackage).